# Facebook Flash API login error

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, api, actionscript

I am having trouble with the following code:

```
    this.fb_init();
}

private function fb_init():void {
    Facebook.init("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",fb_handleInit);
}

private function fb_handleInit(success:Object,fail:Object):void {

    if (success && success.uid) {
         fb_loggedIn(success);
    }else{
        show_FacebookLoginButton();
    }

}

private function show_FacebookLoginButton():void {
    ....
}

private function handleMouseDown_FacebookLoginButton(event:MouseEvent):void {
    _stage.removeChild(_fb_login_button);
    this.fb_login();
}

private function fb_login():void {
    Facebook.login(fb_handleLogin,{scope:"user_games_activity,friends_games_activity"});
}

private function fb_handleLogin(success:Object=null,fail:Object=null):void {
    if (success) {
        fb_loggedIn(success);
    }else{
        show_FacebookLoginButton();
    }
}

private function fb_loggedIn(response:Object) {
    trace("success!);
}
```

First of all, both success and fail are always null in fb_handleInit(success:Object,fail:Object).

Second of all, after login (or immediately if already logged in), fb_handleLogin(success:Object=null,fail:Object=null) is never called and flash outputs the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property expiresIn not found on String and there is no default value.
    at com.facebook.graph.data::FacebookAuthResponse/fromJSON()
    at com.facebook.graph::Facebook/handleAuthResponseChange()
    at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_callIn()
    at Function/<anonymous>()
```

Firebug shows this error message:
    uncaught exception: Error in Actionscript. Use a try/catch block to find error.  xd_arbiter.php line 13 (http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php)

Chrome show this error message:
    Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.

I've been googling and reading about it for a few days, and I've posted an issue at http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/ with no response so far.  I'm surprised the the lack of examples that I can find.  I've found a few and tried them and still had problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook made some changes in auth process, the old version of as3 library (last update of facebook-actionscript-api was in oct. 2011 as mentioned here code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/downloads/list) can result in such errors. Try to find library that's supported.